# unable to inherit TextAppearance.Material.Title.Inverse style in my theme

Tags: android

I get a build error trying to use TextAppearance.Material.Title.Inverse in my theme. I can successfully use TextAppearance.Material.Title so I know I'm set up properly. But add the "Inverse" and build fails. 
Here is style file from res/values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">   
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.AppTheme.Title.Inverse" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

What I wish to accomplish with this style is to override the standard inverse Title style and add in a background attribute so that I have light foreground on a colored background using the default text attributes for the Title style.

I am using API 21, and as mentioned, my build will work with TextAppearance.Material.Title so I know I have the correct SDK, build target, compile target etc., using the correct values-v21 folder 'n all.

The build log reports following error:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
name 'android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title.Inverse'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting more informative message:

> AAPT: error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title.Inverse is private. error: failed linking references.

It seems that the style you are trying to access is not public. You may read more about public/private resources in libraries [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources).

As a workaround you may consider copying the attributes of this style into your own style.